# Why is the question title also in the URL on stackoverflow.com?

Tags: support, questions, title, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the question title (sort of) in the S[OFU] URLs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23255/why-is-the-question-title-sort-of-in-the-sofu-urls)

Every question on stackoverflow.com has the same words in the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) as in the title of the question (just spaces are replaced with dashes). I think this is only for [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization); there is no other reason, I think. Is that the case?

Comment: Also a potential duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108949/question-url-slugs-based-on-title

Comment: It's called a [slug](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_(web_publishing)#section_1), and yes it's for SEO.